# Repeatedly install openpyxl for every Python3 project in Mac

Tags: macos, pycharm, openpyxl, python-3.8

I use Pycharm 2020.1.4 and Python 3.8.5. Everytime I open a new project and want to use openpyxl, I have to go to the preferences (I use Mac), then interpreter, click +, then select openpyxl to be installed. Is this normal? Since I have already installed it via pip3 from Terminal, shouldn't it always be available so that I can just use import openpyxl as xl ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed it on the base Python 3.8.5 on your Mac then when you add a new virtual environment you can select the 'Inherit Global Packages' in Pycharm and you will have whatever packages you installed in the base or global install.

Generally, it is better to have environments that are purpose specific because you may have unintended fallout from doing everything globally. Another way to do this would be to create one environment, name it something like 'data_science_env, and check the 'Make available to all projects' in Pycharm. Then you can reuse it across projects with the same package requirements.